# Append / Remove char in string is different from original string after Append / Remove

Tags: .net, vb.net

I'm actually implementing a char appending function with a char removing function. I'm using a pseudo random number generator with a fixed seed. The final string doesn't look like the initial string, however.

I've checked if my random array is the same in the appending function and the un-appending function. The appending function is the same as the removing function but in reverse.

Here is my appending function :

```
Sub append(ByRef phrase As String)
        Dim size_phrase As Integer = phrase.Length - 1
        Dim i As Integer
        Dim rdm_array(size_phrase) As Integer
        'Dim result As String
        Dim randVar As Random = New Random(seed_charac)
        For i = 0 To size_phrase
            rdm_array(i) = randVar.Next(1, size_phrase)
        Next

        Dim j As Integer
        randVar = New Random()
        For j = 0 To size_phrase
            Dim rdm_Char As Char = Chr(randVar.Next(42, 123))
            phrase = phrase.Insert(rdm_array(j), rdm_Char)
        Next
    End Sub
```

And here is my removingfunction :

```
Sub remove(ByRef phrase As String)
    Dim size_phrase As Integer = phrase.Length - 1
    Dim initialSize As Integer = size_phrase / 2
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim randVar As Random = New Random(seed_charac)
    Dim rdm_array(initialSize) As Integer
    For i = 0 To initialSize
        rdm_array(i) = randVar.Next(1, initialSize)
    Next

    Dim j As Integer
    For j = initialSize To 0 Step -1
        phrase = phrase.Remove(rdm_array(j), 1)
    Next

End Sub
```

And here is my output :

[image]

I would have the same string before and after passing these functions

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Ok sorry, i've edited. I would have the same string before and after passing these functions

Comment: It's almost a question. I guess it's clear enough.

Comment: Can you post how you are using these functions?

Comment: Of course, it's basic way : 
`Dim ch As String = "ABCDEFGHIJ"
 Console.WriteLine("Initial content : " + ch)
 crypt.append(ch)
 Console.WriteLine("content with appened char : " + ch)
 crypt.remove(ch)
 Console.WriteLine("content with removed char : " + ch)
 Console.ReadKey()`

Comment: Have you ever read, here or anywhere else: **Set Option Strict On**?. Do that, correct the error that appears, remove the unused `randVar = New Random()` and you're good to go.

Comment: Why not use functions and return statements instead of byref?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code will not work as you selected indexes at random and how you add new items is not determined to be fixed. This way the index you used when add an item might not be the same when you are removing it due to the fact that later one might modify the string prior to it. This is why you get strange results.

I see where you were going with removing them in the reversed order but that will only work if indexes that you generated are monotonic. If that's the case you can go safely by removing them in reverse order. So in order to make your functions works you would have to sort `rdm_array` before it's being used to either `append` or `remove` characters. Since you are adding characters that increases length of your string and you've already picked your indexes (based on the string length!) I recommend using a decreasing one (it gives more random results).

Additionally I think you have some issues with 'off-by-one' errors. I'm not a VB master (C# is much more easier to read ;) but you should not subtract 1 from length of the string but rather iterate from `0` to `size - 1`.

Taking all that into the consideration final methods should be like this:

```
Sub append(ByRef phrase As String)
    Dim size_phrase As Integer = phrase.Length
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim rdm_array(size_phrase) As Integer
    Dim randVar As Random = New Random(seed_charac)
    For i = 0 To size_phrase - 1
        rdm_array(i) = randVar.Next(1, size_phrase)
    Next
    Array.Sort(rdm_array)
    Array.Reverse(rdm_array)
    Dim j As Integer
    randVar = New Random()
    For j = 0 To size_phrase - 1
        Dim rdm_Char As Char = Chr(randVar.Next(42, 123))
        phrase = phrase.Insert(rdm_array(j), rdm_Char)
    Next
End Sub

Sub remove(ByRef phrase As String)
    Dim size_phrase As Integer = phrase.Length
    Dim initialSize As Integer = size_phrase / 2
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim randVar As Random = New Random(seed_charac)
    Dim rdm_array(initialSize) As Integer
    For i = 0 To initialSize - 1
        rdm_array(i) = randVar.Next(1, initialSize)
    Next
    Array.Sort(rdm_array)
    Array.Reverse(rdm_array)
    Dim j As Integer
    For j = initialSize - 1 To 0 Step -1
        phrase = phrase.Remove(rdm_array(j), 1)
    Next
End Sub
```

[image]

Final note, you example suggest that this might be used for some kind of cryptographic module - if so - please keep it might that it has almost zero value added to your string being encrypted.